# how to interrupt long utterances on google home

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home

I have a very basic/general question:
Is there any way for me to interrupt Google Home while it's talking? I currently have developed an app that asks the user a question. However, I am running into usability issues because the user begins to respond to the question before the mic activates, because they already have predicted the question and as a result the app doesn't pick up their response and waits. The user, however, gets confused because they don't know that the app is waiting for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Users can interrupt Google's reply at any time by starting with "Hey Google" or "OK Google" or the equivalent hotword phrase in their locale. If your action is running, what they say after that will be sent to you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any way it can be interrupted without the user saying "Hey Google" or "OK Google"? The users seem to answer the question just a second or two prior to the microphone opening after the Google Home finishes speaking, so I feel like having the user be required to say "Hey .." or "Ok ..." is not worth it...but there is an awkward pause because the user is expecting that the speaker picked up their response, when it did not, in fact, pick it up.